# Symfony 2: Translate to default locale

Tags: php, symfony, localization, translation

I'm experimenting on Symfony 2 Translation Component. My default locale is el_GR and my alternate locale is en_US. I 've set up my config.yml, I've created 2 translation files: messages.el_GR.yml and messages.en_US.yml and then cleared app/cache. I have translated the word Symfony in both locales. So when I use the command php app/console translation:debug en_US abcNikBundle I get:

```
State | Id       | Message Preview (en_US) | Fallback Message Preview (el_GR)
      | Symfony  | Symfony_US              | Symfony_GR
```

So in a twig template I write

```
{{ 'Symfony'|trans({},'messages') }}
```

It works fine when I use the en_US locale, (it prints Symfony_US) but When I use my default locale (el_GR), it prints Symfony instead of Symfony_GR. Can it be done somehow?

Comment: Try completely deleting the cache directory. Also, if a translation cannot be found it is logged in debug mode - check your logs to see if it couldn't find the translation. Also, you don't have to specify 'messages' since that's the default, you can just do `{{ 'Symfony'|trans }}`

Comment: I deleted the cache directory and it worked! Thank you a lot!

Comment: No problem!  I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your cache is completely deleted.  You probably reset the cache after adding the English translation but not your fallback.  See the [Symfony  documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations) for more info:

> Each time you create a new translation resource (or install a bundle that includes a translation resource), be sure to clear your cache so that Symfony can discover the new translation resources:

Sometimes just running the `cache:clear` command fails for me in which case I just manually delete the contents of the `app/cache` directory.

Also, if a translation cannot be found it is logged in debug mode in the translation channel (*dev.translation.log*) - check your logs to see if it couldn't find the translation. Also, you don't have to specify 'messages' since that's the default, you can just do `{{ 'Symfony'|trans }}`